# using multiple emails in the mail app and sending texts to that app as well

Tags: mail.app, email, iphone

the question is almost identical to the title: i just got an iPhone 5, coming over from a blackberry. on my blackberry i was able to receive all my text messages and emails from both of my accounts (one personal gmail, and one work email address) in one app. is there a way to do this on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

No. All SMS, MMS and iMessages are all collected in Messages.app. All email is, by default, put in Mail.app. There isn't any built-in way to merge the two.

That being said, there is some flexibility to view *multiple inboxes* in Mail.app. While in Mail.app, go back to `Mailboxes` screen and select `All Inboxes`. You will see all the email messages from all of your accounts in a unified view.